# Argument passed for gradle is null android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to install the same app but with different versions/variants. So I found this blog.
https://blog.grandcentrix.net/how-to-install-different-app-variants-on-one-android-device/
I wanted to do something same with the blog's picture with different apps for different sprints
Here's my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def debugsuffix = System.getProperty('debugsuffix', project.getProperties().get('debugsuffix', null))

def final appId = 'com.arthlimchiu.testapp'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = appId
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationId = appId + "." + debugsuffix + ".dev"
            resValue "string", "app_name", ".dev-" + debugsuffix
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

After running this command:

[image]

in Gitbash i'm on windows btw,
debugsuffix is NULL.

Here's a screenshot when I tried to debug it by displaying the debugsuffix as the application name.
[image]

Am I doing the command right? or am I missing something? It's my first time doing this kind gradle thingy btw with passing arguments. Has anyone tried this?It would really be a great help guys :)

Comment: Where are you passing argument? Are you getting build error? If yes what is the error?

Comment: Why are you using MinGW when there is a gradlew.bat for Windows?

Comment: look at the screenshot of my gitbash, debugsuffix is the parameter and i passed "bug44" as its argument.
I don't get build errors though that's why I debugged it by naming my app using the "debugsuffix" variable as you can see it's ".dev-null". The null part is the debugsuffix. I don't know why it's null.

Comment: @cricket_007 I use GitBash for git tasks. I'm a beginner programmer so I just use it since its what I usually saw in tutorials

Comment: @SagarTrehan `-Ddebugsuffix=bug44`... the error is that the property is null in the `app_name` Gradle variable

Comment: `System.getProperty` is returning you null. You are welcome to read the JavaDoc for why that could be

Comment: @SagarTrehan I'm trying to install many of the same app in one device by just modifying the applicationId and appending the "debugsuffix" but as you can see debugsuffix is NULL.

Comment: Did you try `-Pdebugsuffix`? That's what the post says from the terminal

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah I've already tried it a while ago before I posted the question here but it's not working also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it! I actually read the free ebook provided by Gradle. And got an idea how to solve how to install multiple of the same apps in one device.

This is my Gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def debugsuffix = System.getProperty('debugsuffix', project.getProperties().get('debugsuffix', null))

def final appId = 'com.arthlimchiu.testapp'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = appId
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".$debugsuffix"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "testApp-$debugsuffix"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

And the you run this command:

[image: Make sure you use "-P" and it's first executed]

You can chain tasks in your command line separated by space.

And here's the output:

[image]

You can now do something like [AppName]-Sprint1 etc. or [AppName]-bug-fix-05. Something like that.